# Is there a way to add a conditional to an Array definition in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, initialization

I want to add arrays to an ArrayList, but have some values change based on a conditional. The arrays will alway be same size, but the ending values will differ.

You can see in the sample below, the values [1,2,3] are all the same, but either "111" or "222" get written based on the bool.
As of now I have this which works, but I have to repeat the fields and it gets messy when the number of elements in the array increases since you have to duplicate everything and then change out what needs to be changed in the else statement.

```
    boolean bool = true;
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    if(bool){
        arrayList.add(
            new String[]{
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "111",
            "111",
            "111",
            }
        );
    }
    else{
        arrayList.add(
            new String[]{
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "222",
            "222",
            "222"
            }
        );
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayList.toArray()));
```

Is there a way to only declare [1,2,3] once and then have either "111" or "222" be written based off the condition? So something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    arrayList.add(
            new String[]{
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            if(bool) add
            "111","111", "111",
            else add
             "222","222","222"
            }
        );
```

Comment: What makes the *most* sense depends on how you're actually using the `List`. I'd think it'd make sense to keep the constant part constant and eat the cost of array concatenation, or keep things as a list until you explicitly need an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();


String[] toAdd = new String[]{"1","2","3","blah","blah"};

//now we replace blah and blah

if(bool){
   toAdd[3] = "111";
   toAdd[4] = "111";
}else{
   toAdd[3] = "222";
   toAdd[4] = "222";
}

//finally add this new array to the list
arrayList.add(toAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

...

List<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
boolean bool = false;
String[] res = 
        Stream.concat( Stream.of("1","2","3"), 
                       Collections.nCopies(3, bool ? "111" : "222").stream())
              .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    
arrayList.add(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a local variable for the optional field value, this keeps the definition very short - such as:

```
String value = bool ? "111" : "222";
arrayList.add(new String[]{ "1", "2", "3", value, value, value});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 variables which determine

1. what the first part of the array is
2. where to start filling up the array with conditional elements
3. what the conditional element is

namely

```
String[] firstPart = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
int index = 3;
String element = bool ? "111" : "222";
```

and then you copy the first bit and fill up the rest.

```
System.arraycopy(firstPart, 0, a, 0, index);
Arrays.fill(a, index, a.length, element);
arrayList.add(a);
```

The array is initialised plainly

```
String[] a = new String[6];
```